# login disallowed for security issues phpPgAdmin + Deprecated errors

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp

I have performed the usual configuration of xampp:

Open php.ini file located in C:\xampp\php.
Uncomment the following lines in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
Add the below code snippet to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf 
LoadFile "C:\xampp\php\libpq.dll"
```

In C:\xampp\phppgadmin\conf, rename the config.inc.php-dist file to config.inc.php
Edit the config.inc.php and replace all instances of the following with the values below.

```
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\pg_dump.exe';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe';
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

Edit XAMPP’s httpd-xampp.conf and add the below code.

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin/"
<directory "C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require all granted
</directory>
```

I get the following set of errors when I open phpPgAdmin via http://localhost/phppgadmin/:

[image]

Comment: Open terminal or cmd and run `php -v` check what it prints

Comment: @Vinay PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:05:49) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downgrading the xampp and php version.  Added the PHP runtime directory location to the Environment Variables in windows.

Changed the original config.inc to `$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;` and it worked.